# Margin error when using Bulleted List/sublist with newline

Tags: bug, editor

When I want to use sub-list and new line together, line breaks appears on unexpected parts instead of wher it must be.

Like Follows:

```
 * My list item
   * Sublist item
   * Another Sub list
 * Second main list
   * Sublist of second

 * Problematic line break was one line before
   * Another one with upper margin error
   * One more line of sub list element
 * One more list item
   * And its sub element is ok
```

- My list item

  - Sublist item
  - Another Sub list
- Second main list

  - Sublist of second
- Problematic line break was one line before

  - Another one with upper margin error
  - One more line of sub list element
- One more list item

  - And its sub element is ok

A screenshot:

[image: Listing margin error]

Occured on *Ubuntu* with *Firefox 26.0*

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an empty comment `<!-- -->` for things like this. It is sometimes hard for the computer to understand your formatting and a little separation makes things easier.

```
 * My list item
   * Sublist item
   * Another Sub list
 * Second main list
   * Sublist of second

<!-- -->

 * Problematic line break was one line before
   * Another one with upper margin error
   * One more line of sub list element
 * One more list item
   * And its sub element is ok
```

Results:

- My list item

  - Sublist item
  - Another Sub list
- Second main list

  - Sublist of second

- Problematic line break was one line before

  - Another one with upper margin error
  - One more line of sub list element
- One more list item

  - And its sub element is ok